# How to create a tensor index that will have multiple indices?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am new to PyTorch. I need to store id for my validation set in GPU. For example, I will have one id say 1012, now I need to create another set like:

```
tensor results1=(
[102(another id), 12(rank) ], //(another id) and (rank) will not be there
[103(another id),  1(rank) ],
[104(another id),  5(rank) ],
[104(another id) , 1(rank) ]
) 
...
```

What I want is that I can have a tensor variable in GPU like :

```
tensor [1012][results1]
tensor [1013][results2]
```

And also how to retrieve for each index.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is `results1` shape? Is it just a matrix, is it a 3 dimensional tensor? Are those list of different or same shape, is `(rank)` the size of matrix/tensor?

Comment: result1 will be the same shape  and its a matrix. Like one array[I] will hold another array[I1][j1],[i2][j2],[i3][j3].